# Jenkins: shell script - create directory access denied (Linux)

Tags: shell, jenkins

I try to execute a shell script during the build in Jenkins but i get an : "access denied" when i try to create a new folder.

I try to launch a php script in the shell script and i get access denied as well

I launched Jenkins from the .war file.

My question is how to give access to the shell script or user that execute to write in a specific folder?

*I cannot put the chmod to 777 of this folder (too dangerous).*

Comment: What users is jenkins running as? Are you on linux?

Comment: I have no idea for the user sorry, and yes i'm on Linux

Comment: I launched the .war with my user who have all right to create files so i guess is using another one ;) (sorry i'm really a newbie in Linux/Shell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally launched my script through an url with the curl command, and this worked fine.

It's not really a nice solution to the problem but i didn't find any other work around ;)

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix/hack is to change the permissions on the folder Jenkins is trying to write to to 777.

`chmod 777 foldername`

Long term I would figure out what user Jenkins is running as and either change the folder ownership to that user or add Jenkins to whatever group the folder permissions are a part of.

Comment: yes i had this idea but i cannot do this unfortunately, is a web folder so... too dangerous

Comment: Looks like you'll need to figure out what user Jenkins is running as. Mostly likely `jenkins`.

Comment: mh yes :) i think you probably right i'm gonna try this, thanks for the tip !

Comment: i already try to add group to give access jenkins but the addgroup commmand doesn't work... so it's finding someting then something else then something else doesn't work... i already spend 4/5 hours on it :/

Comment: Going to need more info than that. What's the error message? Is there a jenkins user?

Comment: I'm pretty sure but i don't know how to find out if it is the one running the shell script. Is there a command to see which user is running it? (that i can put in the script), thanks for your help by the way ;)

Comment: What is the error message you get when adding the user jenkins via the addgroup command?

Comment: In fact the addgroup command has been removed for security reason, but i finally find the solution to my problem by doing something else (see answer)! Thanks for your help Ryan ;)